# cakephp 3 Routes match /*.php

Tags: cakephp, routes

I'd like to capture all the attempted hacks and just send them to a page.  How can I do that with routes?

I can do this:

```
  $routes->connect('/pma/*',   $hacks);
```

Which works for

```
eg /pma/whatever
```

... but for just routes like

```
/cmd.php
```

I've tried like this:

```
$hacks = ['controller' => 'hacks', 'action' => 'display'];
$routes->connect('/*.php',   $hacks);
```

Which doesn't work, the * doesn't match if it is the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [pattern](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements):

```php
$routes
    ->connect('/:withPhpExt', $hacks)
    ->setPatterns(['withPhpExt' => '.*\.php']);
```

Comment: thanks, had to update from 3.3 -> 3.6 to get that working, but then it works great.